# How Do I Link 2 SharePoint Lists with 1 ID?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I’m assisting with the build of an intake form in power apps. Currently we have 2 separate SharePoint lists linked to the power app.

The issue we’re having is with the ID column.

The ID column values are different (although the rest of the metadata is the same) and we need to see how we can align them in the power app.

Here’s an example:

SharePoint List A:

- ID: 10
- Title: Consumer

SharePoint List B:

- ID: 17
- Title: Consumer

Using the example above, Is there a formula that can be used that will align the ID across the fields in the app?

I understand the ID cannot be changed. Is there a way to link each entry with a common ID?

Answer (score 2):

You have below two options to manage relationship between two lists in SharePoint.

1. **Use lookups**:

You can create a lookup column in 2nd list from 1st list and manage relationship between two lists

**Documentation**: [Create list relationships by using lookup columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632)

2. **Use custom ID column**:

Create a custom column in 2nd list for storing ID column from list 1.

You have to update this column either manually (if less number of items in list) or automate the process using power automate flow by matching Title column in both lists.

Using above ways you will have same ID column in both lists & then you can compare those in power apps.